# .net code coverage does not report number of "partially covered" lines of properties as documented (using dotnet test --collect "Code Coverage")

Tags: .net, code-coverage

Currently, I am trying to include code coverage as part of my automated tests to improve code quality. Using Microsoft's documentation, I am using the dotnet CLI and running `dotnet test --collect "Code Coverage"` to successfully generate a coverage report (.coverage file). However, when I import the results into Visual Studio I am seeing different results than what my understanding of Microsoft's documentation on [reporting in lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#report-in-blocks-or-lines) should produce.

I have a class with a single property:

```
public class ApiStatusMessage
{
   public string APIVersion { get; set; };
}
```

and a unit test only testing the setter of that property (please ignore the "nonsense" purpose of the test but note the write access of `ApiStatusMessage.APIVersion`) :

```
[Fact]
public void CheckServiceVersion()
{
    var apiVersion = new ApiStatusMessage() { APIVersion = "1.0.0" };
}
```

When I now import the generated coverage file into Visual Studio, it does not show the number of covered/uncovered lines as expected.

**Expected outcome:**

According to Microsoft's documentation (see above), this code line should be reported as two blocks (one for the setter as *covered*; one for the getter as *uncovered*) and as a single *partially covered* line since part of the "blocks" it contains were run (the setter) while others were not (the getter).

**Actual outcome:**

The single code line is reported as two blocks (expected) and as two separate lines (unexpected).

[Visual Studio Code Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sKL1.png)

[Visual Studio Line Coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50n6K.png)

Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding when Microsoft describes "lines" of code or does this not match  Microsoft's documentation?